# How to float an element left, wrap text to the side, and center elements below?

Tags: html, css

This is a little hard to describe in just words so I will try my best but the whole thing is up on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a6zuvxL/1/) and there is a snippet below.

I have a modal dialog which is prompting the user to confirm whether or not they want to perform a certain action.

There is an icon (may be a font or image - TBD) on the left. To the right of the icon is a textual prompt which could possibly get quite long so it needs to wrap. When it wraps it should stay in it's "column" rather than go under the icon.

There are also two actions in a Cancel/Yes style which stack on top of each other but need to stay centered. Their box probably needs to overlap the icon to take up any available vertical space.

It looks something like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|XXX  Are you sure?     |
|XXX                    |
|XXX       Yes          |
|         Cancel        |
+-----------------------+
```

or this if the prompt is long:

```
+-----------------------+
|XXX  Are you sure?     |
|XXX  blah blah blah    |
|XXX  blah blah blah    |
|     blah blah blah    |
|          Yes          |
|         Cancel        |
+-----------------------+
```

I have tried to float the icon and use inline-block however it breaks either the wrapping, centering, or overlapping buttons.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.clearfix:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 content: " ";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
}

.ion-trash-b {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.hack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  width: 300px;
}

.context {
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

a {
  color: #07d;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="parent clearfix">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="ion-trash-b left"></div>
    <h3>Delete</h3>
    <p>Are you sure?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hack clearfix">
    <button>Yes</button>
    <a>No</a>
  </div>
</div>

This is what I want but preferably without any fixed sizes or positions.

<hr />

<div class="parent clearfix">
  <div class="ion-trash-b left"></div>
  <h3>Delete</h3>
  <p>Are you sure?</p>
  <button>Yes</button>
  <a>No</a>
</div>

Buttons and links not centered.

<hr />

<div class="parent clearfix">
  <div class="ion-trash-b left"></div>
  <h3>Delete</h3>
  <p>Are you sure? (This actually may get quite long and still needs to wrap correctly. As you can see this doesn't work quite right. Oops still not quite there yet... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah)</p>
  <button>Yes</button>
  <a>No</a>
</div>

Doesn't wrap correctly.

<hr />

<div class="parent clearfix">
  <div class="ion-trash-b left"></div>
  <h3>Delete</h3>
  <p class="context">Are you sure? (This actually may get quite long and still needs to wrap correctly. As you can see this doesn't work quite right. Oops still not quite there yet... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah)</p>
  <button>Yes</button>
  <a>No</a>
</div>

Almost there but...

<hr />

<div class="parent clearfix">
  <div class="ion-trash-b left"></div>
  <h3>Delete</h3>
  <p class="context">Are you sure?</p>
  <button>Yes</button>
  <a>No</a>
</div>

... Haven't solved the first problem.

<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable with flexbox?

On the CSS side, what I basically did was set `.parent` to `display: flex`. I also added some `padding-right` to the icon.

On the HTML, I wrapped everything inside `.parent` that's not the icon in a `div.right-section`. This gives the right side a column-like feel, which should address the wrapping.

No fixed-widths used on any of the elements inside of the `.parent`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex; // added
  width: 300px;
}

.ion-trash-b {
  font-size: 100px;
  padding-right: 15px; // added but not necessary
}

button {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

a {
  color: #07d;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="parent clearfix">
  <div class="ion-trash-b left"></div>
  
  <!-- added div to group content -->
  <div class="right-section">
    <h3>Delete</h3>
    <p class="context">Are you sure? (This actually may get quite long and still needs to wrap correctly. As you can see this doesn't work quite right. Oops still not quite there yet... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah)</p>
    <button>Yes</button>
    <a>No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is pretty much the same as my last attempt. The buttons need to be both centered and take up blank space vertically.